# Interrogate all user claims to check for duplicates

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am using AspNetCore Identity and I need to be able to interrogate every claim value to see if a value exists? I am storing user alias as a claim for every user and dont want duplicates. I cant see a way of doing this without loading every user and then looking at all claims for the user?

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public async Task<bool> CheckAlias(string alias)
{
    // Check if alias exists, if yes then return true else return false


    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by getting all users with a claim and then counting the results

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public async Task<bool> CheckAlias(string alias)
{
    var users = await _userManager.GetUsersForClaimAsync(new Claim("Alias", alias));

    if (users.Count > 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```